# how to locate a program to desktop by C#

Tags: c#, desktop

i want to do a program that like daily organizer or agenda. i want that program runs on desktop like a wallpaper but as transparantly. (like the clock on vista). how can achieve this by c#. i only ask to locate program on desktop.

thanks.

Comment: You can check out http://www.nikhilk.net/SidebarGadgets.aspx on how to make a Vista Gadget.

Comment: If you don't need to interact with the application, make an app which runs in the background and changes the desktop background to an image of your agenda. Could you provide more information?

Comment: @devadam4 a bit more background research would have helped you to articulate a question properly to get an asnwer that can guide you. At least to save from being closed as a "Not a real questions..."

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a [Windows Sidebar Gadget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965850(VS.85).aspx), which is typically an HTML "application", an HTML "application" that hosts Flash (Silverlight may work as well, although I'm not sure), or a C# application, as shown [here](http://www.nikhilk.net/SidebarGadgets.aspx).

Comment: "Writing a Windows Sidebar Gadget in Silverlight--dead simple!" http://blogs.msdn.com/charles_sterling/archive/2007/05/14/writing-a-windows-sidebar-gadget-in-silverlight-dead-simple.aspx